# how to obtain these increasing integers for given n and m?

Tags: list-manipulation, integer-sequence

Let `n` and `m` be natural numbers. Then, how does one write a function `ordint[n,m]` that gives every $2n$ integers ${a_1,...,a_n,b_1,...,b_n}$ such that $0\leq a_1$, $a_i < a_j$ if $i < j$, $a_n \leq b_1$, $b_i < b_j$ if $i < j$, and $b_n \leq m$? For example, the following `ordint2[m]` gives the desired output for `n=2`.

```
ordint2[m_]:=Module[{S,A,B},
 S={};
 Do[S=Append[S,{A[1],A[2],B[1],B[2]}],
    {B[2],0,m},{B[1],0,B[2]-1},{A[2],0,B[1]},{A[1],0,A[2]-1}];
 S]
```

But, I do not know how to implement the varying index condition
`{B[n],0,m},{B[n-1],0,B[n]-1},....,{B[1],0,B[2]-1},{A[n],0,B[1]},{A[n-1],0,A[n]-1},...,{A[1],0,A[2]-1}` to write `ordint[n,m]` for a general n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the start, you can try this one:

```
ordint[m_Integer?Positive, n_Integer?Positive] := Join @@ Table[
   (* searching for all lists with a[[n]] = k <= b[[1]]*)
   Join[
    (* searching for all lists with a[[n]]= k = b[[1]]*)
    Partition[
     Flatten[
      Outer[
       Join,
       Subsets[Range[0, k - 1], {n - 1}],
       {{k}},
       {{k}},
       Subsets[Range[k + 1, m], {n - 1}],
       1
       ]
      ], 
      2 n],
    (* searching for all lists with a[[n]] = k < b[[1]]*)
    Partition[
     Flatten[
      Outer[
       Join,
       Subsets[Range[0, k - 1], {n - 1}],
       {{k}},
       Subsets[Range[k + 1, m], {n}],
       1
       ]
      ], 
      2 n]
    ],
   {k, n - 1, m - n + 1}]

ordint[3, 2]
```

> {{0, 1, 1, 2}, {0, 1, 1, 3}, {0, 1, 2, 3}, {0, 2, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 2, 3}}

Comment: Thank you very much! But, you need to vary k in the code, right? Indeed, I got erros such as "Table::iterb: Iterator {k,1,3-k} does not have appropriate bounds" by Clear[k]; ordint[3,2].

Comment: Oops. Fixed it. Please try againg.

Comment: Yes, now it gives correct outputs! Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.